# Why do I get "Kernel panic" error during the docker run?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecr

Jenkins was running as a container inside an old EC2 instance which was having Ubuntu18.0 and then I created an image from the running containerand pushed into ECR in aws. Then I launched a new instance with ubuntu20.0 and installed docker and pulled the same image from ECR and ran it like below.

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 e0f499cc9f6e
```

And I get below message in the terminal

```
Message from syslogd@ip-10-133-184-109 at Jun 10 09:21:52 ...
kernel:[ 9974.261090] Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt

Message from syslogd@ip-10-133-184-109 at Jun 10 09:21:52 ...
kernel:[ 9974.261090] Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt
```

But the default docker image **hello-world** from docker-hub works fine. What may be the issue here?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]; make sure to include the source code and error messages as plain text and not image files.

Comment: Voting to close as "not reproducible or unlikely to help future readers" as this is a very time-limited bug.

Answer (score 1):

A recently released linux kernel (`5.13.0-1028-aws` for AWS) contained a [bug which caused a kernel panic when using docker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-aws-5.13/+bug/1977919). A fix has been released a few hours ago. If you are running the affected kernel a system update & reboot to the new kernel (`5.13.0-1029-aws`) will fix it.